# Plot Y bar from zero and not at the smaller value of list

Tags: python, matplotlib

Any suggestion of how to plot it correctly starting the Y bar with a zero?

using this dictionary:

```
D = {
    'GCF_000416945.1': '450',
    'GCF_001294115.1': '451',
    'GCF_000245395.1': '416',
    'GCF_002318825.1': '451',
    'GCF_001401215.1': '450',
    'GCF_000935735.1': '450'
}
```

and these lines:

```
plt.bar(range(len(D)), D.values(), align='center')  # python 2.x
plt.xticks(range(len(D)), D.keys())
```

[image]

Comment: `plt.ylim([0, 500])` perhaps? Btw, I can not reproduce your issue. My plots start from 0.

Comment: before or after the line 'plt.bar'?

Comment: I would do after, but this is essentially the same as @Giogos's answer below. If that didn't work, then it's likely that your problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: What version of `python` and `matplotlib` are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert all your dictionary values to integers as an error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'` will be raised with the current code. When the latter error is corrected, the code achieves the correct result in Python2:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
D = {
'GCF_000416945.1': '450',
'GCF_001294115.1': '451',
'GCF_000245395.1': '416',
'GCF_002318825.1': '451',
'GCF_001401215.1': '450',
'GCF_000935735.1': '450'
}
plt.bar(range(len(D)), map(int, D.values()), align='center')
plt.xticks(range(len(D)), D.keys())
```

[image]

Comment: The code works fine for me without converting to `int`. Could it be a `matplotlib` version issue?

Comment: @pault strange, I ran this in Python2. What version did you use?

Comment: python 2.7.13 and matplotlib 2.0.0

Comment: the same as me.

Answer (score 0):

The following line should do the trick:

```
plt.ylim(ymin=0)
```

Comment: I continue with the same problem. It did not work for me.